# How to access a dynamic task without making it static

Tags: java, swing

Just a quick question today, I've made a `JFrame`, and when i click the "Let's do this!" button I'd like it to add a new task to the array list in "Woodcutter" here's my code, any help is appreciated.

```
package org.script.gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import org.script.Constants;

public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        switch (action.getActionCommand().toLowerCase()) {
        case "let's do this!":
            //TODO i want this to be able to change taskList from Woodcutter!
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(action.getActionCommand().toLowerCase()+" - COMMAND NOT ADDED!");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

and in a seperate class i have this :

```
public List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can i change the value of taskList from the `ActionHandler` class without making it static? thanks.

EDIT: heres my Woodcutter class

```
package org.script;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.powerbot.script.PollingScript;
import org.powerbot.script.rt6.ClientContext;
import org.script.gui.ScriptSettings;
import org.script.task.Task;

public class Woodcutter extends PollingScript<ClientContext> {

    public List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start() {
        ScriptSettings.main(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void poll() {
        for (Task task : taskList) {
            if (task.activate()) {
                task.execute();
            }
        }
    }

    public void verifyOptions() {
        if (Constants.FLETCHING && Constants.BONFIRES) {
            sendError("You cant fletch and use bonfires!");
        } else if (Constants.BONFIRES && Constants.BANKING) {
            sendError("You cant use bonfires and bank!");
        } else if (Constants.BANKING && Constants.FLETCHING) {
            sendError("You cant bank and fletch!");
        } else {
            taskList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Dropper(ctx)));
        }
    }

    private void sendError(String message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

EDIT 2 - Even if i do make it static, i can't make a static reference to the non static field ctx.

Comment: Pass a reference of the `List` to the `ActionHandler`

Answer (score 1):

Your ActionHandler should hold an instance of the woodcutter class.  You can either inject the dependency, or have it eagerly created as in my example.  The woodcutter class should have a get method for the taskList, which simple returns the list.  Search google for getter and setter methods for more info on that.

```
package org.script.gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import org.script.Constants;

public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    private Woodcutter wc = new Woodcutter();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        switch (action.getActionCommand().toLowerCase()) {
        case "let's do this!":
            wc.getTaskList().add(new Task());
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(action.getActionCommand().toLowerCase()+" - COMMAND NOT ADDED!");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried doing that, getting this error                                
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to org.powerbot.bot.coN
 at org.powerbot.script.AbstractScript.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.powerbot.script.PollingScript.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.script.Woodcutter.<init>(Woodcutter.java:20)
 at org.script.gui.ActionHandler.<init>(ActionHandler.java:11)
 at org.script.gui.ScriptSettings.<init>(ScriptSettings.java:48)
 at org.script.gui.ScriptSettings.main(ScriptSettings.java:23)

Comment: Can you post all the relevent code to your question?

Comment: added Woodcutter class to main post, you need anything else?

Comment: I think there are deeper problems here.  Your woodcutter class references your ScriptSettings main class, which I assume calls the powerbot PollingScript class?  Your stack trace suggests that the exception is being thrown in the powerbot code for AbstractScript (which I have to assume PollingScript extends).  Not knowing anything about powerbot, I suggest you start a new question for this problem, hoopefully someone out there has used it before!